# IN @variable does not allow selection of multiple categories

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

The following query which I am currently making into a report in MS report Builder does not allow me to choose all categories within the department. When I select a specific category it seems to work but not with all categories.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use dynamic SQl for that. Or send the values into a table that the report uses. Or use a stored proc as the source and use a split function to put the values in a temp table. What you are trying to do the way you are trying to do it is simply impossible.

And if you are writing reporting queries, you need to stop using correlated subqueries as they run row-by-agonizing-row and are extremely slow with the large amounts of data that tend to be in a report.

Comment: So just send all the values into a TABLE using stored proc and then create a cursor to calculate the variance and total....And then from there select the required values....??

Comment: no cursor, never use a cursor. There is no need for a cursor. You are trying to avoid using them. Joins you need Joins. And maybe CTEs or derived tables.